# Hasura permission denied for table on insert

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, hasura

I'm attempting to do an insert on a table in Hasura's UI. I am getting permission denied even though I'm executing the query inside the api-explorer.

```
          "error": {
            "exec_status": "FatalError",
            "hint": null,
            "message": "permission denied for table players",
            "status_code": "42501",
            "description": null
          },
```

My insert mutation:

```
mutation insert_players($objects: [players_insert_input!]!) {
  insert_players(objects: $objects, on_conflict: {
      constraint: players_pkey,
      update_columns: [
         ...
         accelRating 
         age 
         ...
      ]
    }) {
    returning {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku row limit was hit on the hobby dev plan. This can be checked on the heroku postgres add-on.

[image]

See this answer for more detail:
[Heroku PG: Recover Write access revoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22199592/heroku-pg-recover-write-access-revoked)

Comment: how to see it ?